# In which jar of tika I must to depend?

Tags: java, dependencies, apache-tika

I want to use `Tika` for extracting the text of some file formates like `.doc`, `.ppt` and so on.
Currently I'm depended to `tika-app-1.2.jar`, but I think depending to this jar is not a good idea because this jar is runnable. Moreover in parsing the `.ppt` files it gives me this Runtime Exception:

```
org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: Unexpected RuntimeException from  org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser@5de82b72
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:244)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:242)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:120)
    ...
```

I have deeply googled this problem and found out that this problem is caused by `apache-poi` which is embedded in `tika-app`.

My question is that in which jars of tika I must to depend?

- tika
- tika-core
- tika-bundle
- tika-parent
- tika-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://tika.apache.org/1.3/gettingstarted.html

I think you want the tika-parsers dependency. From the Tika website.

> If you want to use Tika to parse documents (instead of simply
>   detecting document types, etc.), you'll want to depend on tika-parsers
>   instead:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
  <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

As a side note, I would never try to grab a dependency directly from Maven central without first consulting the documentation for that project. Breaking out the dependencies as you see in Tika is, IMO, the new standard way of doing it instead of providing a single monolithic jar so that people including those projects can have finer grain control what they pull in to their own project when including a dependency.